# Create tree structured JSON

Tags: json, delphi, recursion

I have a list of objects, of type TDepartment which looks like this

```
TDepartment = class
  ID : Integer;
  Name : string;
  ParentDepartmentID : Integer;
end;
```

I need to create a TJSONObject, with an array of departments, which all can also have an array of departments. So the depth of this is unknown.

I am at a point right now where it simply doesn't make sense to me, but I would like the resulting JSON to look like this:

```
    "department_id": "5",
    "department_name": "100",
    "parent_dept_id": "",
    "subdepartments": [{
        "department_id": "8",
        "department_name": "300",
        "parent_dept_id": "5",
        "subdepartments": [{
            "department_id": "1",
            "department_name": "310",
            "parent_dept_id": "8",
            "subdepartments": []
```

Keep in mind that each level has unknown amount of siblings and children.
I guess i need to write a recursive procedure, but I am unable to visualize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you probably want your declaration of `TDepartment`to match the nested structure you describe:

```
TDepartment = class
  ID : Integer;
  Name : string;
  ParentDepartmentID : Integer;
  SubDepartments: array of TDepartment;
end;
```

In order to serialize this I would recommend using the SuperObject library rather than the inbuilt JSON classes:

```
function TDepartment.Serialize: ISuperObject;
  var Context: TSuperRttiContext;
begin
  Context := TSuperRttiContext.Create;
  try
    Result := Context.AsJson<TDepartment>(self);
  finally
    Context.Free;
  end;
end;
```

In the comments, OP mentioned that `TDepartment` contains a lot more fields, but only the ones in the question should be serialized; also `TJSONObject` has to be used, and a department does not know about its children. You could do something like that:

```
function TDepartment.Serialize2(AllDepartments: TList<TDepartment>): TJSONObject;
  var Department: TDepartment;
      Subdepartments: TJSONArray;
begin
  Result := TJSONObject.Create;
  Result.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('department_id', TJSONNumber.Create(ID)));
  Result.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('department_name', Name));
  Result.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('parent_dept_id', TJSONNumber.Create(ParentDepartmentID)));

  Subdepartments := TJSonArray.Create;
  for Department in AllDepartments do
  begin
    if (Department.ParentDepartmentID <> ID) then Continue;
    Subdepartments.AddElement(Department.Serialize2(AllDepartments));
  end;
  Result.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('subdepartments', Subdepartments));
end;
```

Comment: I simplified the code just to make an example, in reality TDepartments has hundreds of properties and fields, it is part of a million+ line codebase in an older framework, so the JSON and TDepartment does indeed match.
This is also why I need to use the built in JSON classes, as they are used throughout the application.

Comment: Do you want to serialize all fields of TDepartment to the JSON, or just the ones in your example?

Comment: Just the ones in my example :) but it is worth noting that the only relation between a parent and its child is the "parent_department_id", and the department itself does NOT have a "subdepartments" property

Comment: That's a pretty poor way of modeling the parent-child-relationship then ... I don't believe you can easily serialize a class to TJSONObject, but if you only need a few of the fields, you probably want to roll your own anyways. Have a look at the edit to my answer.

Comment: @MattBaech SuperObject is indeed easier to use and better tested. You probably can create it, then export it as JSON string, then load your TJSONObject from that string. You can register your custom serializer for TDepartment, then use SuperObject built in typecast to make the work

Answer (score 0):

I would create a parallel tree structure leaving the original intact. Your current structure is inverted as to what you need, so you scan through your current objects placing them in the tree. But without knowing the current structure this is difficult give sample code, but assuming all departments exist in some sort of list, (let us say called 'Departments') and the 'root' department has a parent department ID of zero it would go something like this:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TDepartment = class
    ID : Integer;
    Name : string;
    ParentDepartmentID : Integer;
  end;

  TDepartmentStructure = class
    ID : Integer;
    Name : string;
    ParentDepartmentID : Integer;
    SubDepartments: TList< TDepartmentStructure >;
    constructor Create( const pBasedOn : TDepartment );
  end;

var
  Department : TObjectList<TDepartment>;

function CopyStructure( pDepartment : TList<TDepartment> ) : TDepartmentStructure; // returns root

implementation

var
  DepartmentStructure : TObjectList<TDepartmentStructure>;

function CopyStructure( pDepartment : TList<TDepartment> ) : TDepartmentStructure;
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  // stage one - copy everything
  for i := 0 to pDepartment.Count - 1 do
  begin
    DepartmentStructure.Add( TDepartmentStructure.Create( pDepartment[ i ] ));
  end;
  // now go through and build structure
  Result := nil;
  for i := 0 to DepartmentStructure.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if DepartmentStructure[ i ].ID = 0 then
    begin
      // root
      Result := DepartmentStructure[ i ];
    end
    else
    begin
      for j := 0 to DepartmentStructure.Count - 1 do
      begin
        if DepartmentStructure[ i ].ParentDepartmentID = DepartmentStructure[ j ].ID then
        begin
          DepartmentStructure[ j ].SubDepartments.Add( DepartmentStructure[ i ] );
          break;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

{ TDepartmentStructure }

constructor TDepartmentStructure.Create(const pBasedOn: TDepartment);
begin
  inherited Create;
  ID := pBasedOn.ID;
  Name := pBasedOn.Name;
  ParentDepartmentID := pBasedOn.ParentDepartmentID;
  SubDepartments:= TObjectList< TDepartmentStructure >.Create( FALSE ); // we do NOT own these objects!

end;

initialization
  DepartmentStructure := TObjectList<TDepartmentStructure>.Create( TRUE );

finalization
  DepartmentStructure.Free;

end.
```

Note that this is for illustration purposes only. You would probably not create and destroy the structures where I have. Once you have the structure you can create your JSON records using your current routines no doubt.